# Access Violation during Delphi 6 program startup in GetKeyboardType() Windows API call

Tags: .net, delphi, access-violation, vcl

I have a Delphi 6 application that works fine on one of my PCs.  I recently spent the day duplicating my entire programming environment to another PC because a bug I have been wrestling with only occurred on that other PC.  I moved over all the code, the libraries such as the JEDI JVCL 3.0 and all the others that are necessary, duplicated the environment and project paths, and installed all the necessary VCL components, etc.  Note, I am using FastMM4 as my memory manager.

However, when I try to run the Delphi 6 app I get an Access Violation when the program is initializing.  The error occurs in the **System** unit during the GetKeyboardType() Windows API call in the following function:

```
function _isNECWindows: Boolean;
var
  KbSubType: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  if GetKeyboardType(0) = $7 then
  begin
    KbSubType := GetKeyboardType(1) and $FF00;
    if (KbSubType = $0D00) or (KbSubType = $0400) then
      Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

This does not happen on my main development station.  Here are some other anecdotal data points:

- Despite not having any break points in the Project File source, the debugger always stops on the "begin" statement in that file.  I hit F9 to continue on.
- Originally the program was throwing the A/V from MSVCR80.dll.  I am not sure why this happened since I don't think any of my code uses that DLL, so I found all copies of that DLL and neutered them by renaming them to .sav.  I then rebuilt and continued on.
- The CPU window shows the error happening during an assembler CALL statement, inside the kernel function named **ntdll.KiUserCallbackDispatcher()**.

Can anyone give me some things to try to rectify this problem?

**UPDATE**: I restored MSVCR80.DLL to its proper name to do some more testing.  If I do that, then I get an A/V when **SysUtils** initializes.  I put a breakpoint right on the **initialization** statement.  As soon as I step over that line I get an the A/V deep within the memory manager.  The call stack shows:

```
@GetMem(???)
@NewAnsiString(???)
@StartExe(???)
@InitExe(???)
[the project name]
```

It seems as if MSVCR80.DLL is tied into the memory manager somehow and something is blowing up during a memory allocation.  When I was duplicating the programming environment I remember seeing a couple of .NET warnings when I ran the Delphi Installation program from the **Add and Remove Programs** control panel applet.  I needed to remove some old Indy components before installing the latest ones, so I used the **Modify** option of the Delphi installation program.  During that process I get a couple of warning boxes about .NET.  I didn't write down the messages since my Delphi app does not use any .NET DLLs or libraries so I believed the messages to be spurious.  Perhaps there is some weird entanglement here that I need to fix first?

Comment: have you tried your application in a "clean" VM? maybe there's something "special" about this system...

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. This exception throws in case absence of needed dll module. In my case it was Full_DebugMode.dll